# Email opts in in sunchronised data extention frrom salesfoce to marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder, sales-cloud, data-synchronization

I am using the marketing cloud connect to transfer data from the sales cloud to the marketing cloud. In sales cloud I see that there is a field HasOptedOut which we are using as marketing permission. But this field is not shown in marketing cloud . Is it so that only data with value false are sent to marketing cloud or is there any way I can find send this field to MC. Thank you

Comment: The functionality works like, when subscriber status of a [Contact/Lead] is changed to `Unsubscribed` in Marketing CLoud, then the `HasOptedOutOfEmail` fields get updated to TRUE in Sales cloud.

Comment: Hi @Sandeep, you mean to say to couldn't able to see the field in syncing it from the contact builder itself? If yes, please check on the field level permission of the field in salesforce which you have set it to marketing cloud connect user. If not, can you please let me know where you couldn't able to see it in marketing cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check field level security in Sales Cloud. The integration user used to connect SFMC to SFSC needs to have a profile that can see HasOptedOutOfEmail or your custom field called "HasOptedOut" (caution).